# How do I make the back button work when navigating back to an Angular app?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, browser-history

I have an app which uses AngularJS for some of its newer pages, and legacy server-side generated templates on other pages. When a person navigates from an Angular page to a server-side templated page, then uses the browser back button to return to the Angular page, none of the JavaScript responsible for making Angular page runs. This leaves the Angular page in a bad state.

I thought that the browser's bfcache would retain the state of the page just as it was when the user navigated out. However apparently I don't understand how bfcache works, it seems to do nothing except put back superficial HTML template code.

The app does not use the $location service, since I don't want to make Angular responsible for app-wide routing (yet): it would be too invasive to existing legacy code.

In any case, the problem should be exactly the same if an Angular app has a link to an external site: user clicks the link, visits the external site, then clicks the back button to a broken Angular page.

What am I missing to make this case work?

It would be nice to avoid gross kludges with checking some hidden state and issuing a broad location.reload() at the very beginning of all JS execution, but I don't mind forcing controller reinstantiation.

Comment: Angular routing, like most other MV* frameworks, intercepts the browser navigation and passes it to the router, then stops the page navigation which would normally occur.  Navigating away from the angular site unloads the code and all the variables in memory, so hitting back would only work if the entire app state can be recreated from the last url handled.

Comment: Fully unloading the code and all variables in memory for the Angular site seems remarkably drastic. Is there no reasonable workaround?

Comment: you are dealing with JavaScript and the browser, which deal with each page load as a unique application instance.  you can potentially store variables in cookies or LocalStorage and reload them if they exist from a previous visit each time the page loads, but it's terribly cumbersome.  The only other option you have is to structure your routes VERY carefully so that every angular page that is rendered could be stateless.  However, you are limiting the utility of Angular as a Single Page Application Framework in that way.

Answer (score 0):

In a single page application(SPA) with the routings properly configure you can use `$routeChangeSucess` to track the route changes like this:

In your *MainController*:

```
scope.history = [];

$scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function (event, current, previous) {         
        //this is how your track of the navigation history
        $scope.history.push($location.$$path);
    });


///Your go back code function can works something similar to this
   $scope.goBack = function(){       
        var prevUrl = $scope.history.length > 1 ? $scope.history.splice(-2)[0] : "/";
        $location.path(prevUrl);
    };
```